# AJAX request not work with some HTML tags in the input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very wired problem I send AJAX request from a form to the server "Apache" to a PHP endpoint.
If the input have some tags like `<script>` not working and return 404 error. if I changed to `<scrip>` or any thing else work fine.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.js_ajax-forms', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url =  $(this).data('url');
        $.post(ajax_path+url, {'code': JSON.stringify($(this).find('textarea').val())}, function(response) {
            consol.log('Success');
        }, "json")
        .fail(function() {
            consol.log('Error');
        });
    });
```

The URL will be something like `domain.com/api/post.php?edit=code`

And HTML Code comes from Google Analytics

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your html. In practice your JavaScript should live in it's own file separate from the html. I am not sure how you are incorporating the <script> tags, but it sounds like bad practice.

Comment: can you post your html code too?

Comment: The HTML code comes from Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your HTML so will take a guess. Instead of stringifying try to send encoded string as post data.

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

$('body').on('submit', '.js_ajax-forms', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url =  $(this).data('url');
        $.post(ajax_path+url, htmlEncode($(this).find('textarea').val())), function(response) {
            consol.log('Success');
        }, "json")
        .fail(function() {
            consol.log('Error');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You may also try using `encodeURI()` instead of `htmlEncode`